# Input value updated via JS won't display

Tags: javascript, input

I'm creating and setting a default value for an input (type is left default, but when specifically set to text, I get the same problem) element. The value, according to JS, does update, but I don't see the change in either the displayed page or source.

```
    temp3 = document.createElement('input'); temp2.appendChild(temp3);
    temp3.value = "a";
```

If I check the value, via alert(temp3.value), I do see "a", but I see no change on the created text input on the page, nor when I check via Chrome's Inspect element feature.

Comment: It is a li element. But it shouldn't matter, I have have another element (select) also being attached, and it works just fine. I can also add div elements just fine. Just the inputs being strange.

Comment: Probably doesn't matter, but you might as well try setting  temp3.type = 'text';  just in case that has any effect.  Also, make sure to check in different browsers as they sometimes have different error messages.

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't change anything. :/ It's a Chrome extension options page, so I doubt it needs to be cross-browser compatible, but I'll check it in IE for hopes of an error message (I don't get one as it is).